# C++ Visual Studio 2019 class templates returning long slate of errors, some guidance would be appreciated

Tags: c++, class-template

This is my first time using function/class templates in C++, and I am having trouble getting to the bottom of some errors that are appearing in my code.

My program uses a Linked List template class and a Node template class. You can see the relevant code below.

**Main**

```
int main()
{
    cout << "Printing linked list \"my_list\", instantiating the template class with a string:\n" << endl;
    LList<string> my_list("first");
    my_list.insertTail("second");
    my_list.insertHead("three");
    my_list.printList();

    cout << "Printing linked list \"my_list_2\", instantiating the template class with an 
int:\n" << endl;

    LList<int> my_list_2(1);
    my_list_2.insertTail(2);
    my_list_2.insertHead(3);
    my_list_2.printList();

    cout << "Printing linked list \"my_list_3\", instantiating the template class with a `float:\n" << endl;`
    LList<float> my_list_3(1.111111);
    my_list_3.insertTail(2.222222);
    my_list_3.insertHead(3.333333);
    my_list_3.printList();

    return 0;
}
```

**Node class**

```
template <typename T>
class Node
{
    friend class LList<T>
private:
    T m_data;
    Node* next_ptr;
public:
    Node();
    Node(T in, Node* innext);
    Node(Node& copy);
    Node(Node&& move);
    ~Node();
    T getData();
    void setData(T in);
    Node& operator =(Node& copy);
    Node& operator =(Node&& move);
};

template <typename T>
Node<T>::Node()
    : next_ptr(nullptr)
{}
template <typename T>
Node<T>::Node(T in, Node* innext)
    : m_string(instring), next_ptr(innext)
{}
template <typename T>
Node<T>::Node(Node& copy)
    : m_data(copy.m_data), next_ptr(copy.next_ptr)
{}
template <typename T>
Node<T>::Node(Node&& move)
    : m_data(move.m_data), next_ptr(move.next_ptr)
{
    move.m_data = "";
    move.next_ptr = 0;
}
template <typename T>
Node<T>::~Node()
{
    //delete next_ptr?
}
template <typename T>
T Node<T>::getData()
{
    return m_data;
}
template <typename T>
void Node<T>::setData(T in)
{
    m_data = in;
}
template <typename T>
Node<T>& Node<T>::operator =(Node& copy)
{
    m_data = copy.m_data;
    next_ptr = copy.next_ptr;

    return *this;
}
template <typename T>
Node<T>& Node<T>::operator =(Node&& move)
{
    m_data = move.m_data;
    next_ptr = move.next_ptr;

    move.m_data = NULL;
    move.next_ptr = 0;

    return *this;
}
```

**Linked List class**

```
template <typename T>
class LList
{
private:
    Node<T>* m_head;
public:
    LList();
    LList(T in);
    LList(const LList& copy);
    LList(LList&& move);
    ~LList();
    Node* getNode(int pos);
    void insertHead(T in);
    void insertTail(T in);
    void deleteNode(T in);
    void printList();
    LList& operator =(LList& copy);
    LList& operator =(LList&& move);
};
template <typename T>
LList<T>::LList<T>()
{
    Node* newNode = new Node;
    m_head = newNode;
}
template <typename T>
LList<T>::LList<T>(T in)
{
    Node* newNode = new Node;
    m_head = newNode;
    newNode->setData(in);
}
template <typename T>
LList<T>::LList<T>(const LList& copy)
{
    Node* newNode = new Node;
    *newNode = *(copy.m_head);
    m_head = newNode;
    m_head->next_ptr = nullptr;

    Node* temp = copy.m_head;
    while (temp->next_ptr != nullptr)
    {
        temp = temp->next_ptr;
        this->insertTail(temp->getData());
    }
}
template <typename T>
LList<T>::LList<T>(LList&& move)
    : m_head(move.m_head)
{
    move.m_head = 0;
}
template <typename T>
LList<T>::~LList<T>()
{
    Node* next = nullptr;

    while (m_head != nullptr)
    {
        next = m_head->next_ptr;
        delete m_head;
        m_head = next;
    }

    delete next;
}
template <typename T>
Node<T>* LList<T>::getNode(int pos)
{
    Node* traverse = m_head;

    for (int i = 0; i < pos; i++)
    {
        traverse = traverse->next_ptr;
    }

    return traverse;
}
template <typename T>
void LList<T>::insertHead(T in)
{
    Node* newNode = new Node;

    Node* temp = m_head;
    m_head = newNode;

    newNode->next_ptr = temp;

    m_head->setData(in);
}
template <typename T>
void LList<T>::insertTail(T in)
{
    Node* newNode = new Node;

    Node* temp = this->m_head;
    while (m_head->next_ptr != nullptr)
    {
        this->m_head = m_head->next_ptr;
    }
    this->m_head->next_ptr = newNode;
    this->m_head->next_ptr->setData(in);

    this->m_head = temp;
}
template <typename T>
void LList<T>::deleteNode(T in)
{
    if (m_head->next_ptr == nullptr)
    {
        delete m_head;
    }
    else
    {
        Node* temp = m_head;
        Node* prev = nullptr;
        if (m_head->getData() == in)
        {
            Node* temp = m_head->next_ptr;
            delete m_head;
            m_head = temp;
        }
        else
        {
            Node* temp = m_head;
            Node* prev = nullptr;
            while (m_head->getData() != in)
            {
                prev = m_head;
                m_head = m_head->next_ptr;
                if (m_head == nullptr)
                {
                    cout << "ERROR: No node with data \"" << in << "\" appears in your linked list, so no deletion can be made\n";
                    return;
                }
            }
            prev->next_ptr = m_head->next_ptr;
            delete m_head;
            m_head = temp;
        }
    }
}
template <typename T>
void LList<T>::printList()
{
    Node* temp = m_head;
    int i = 1;

    cout << "<CONTENTS>\n" << endl;
    while (m_head != nullptr)
    {
        cout << "Node " << i << " -" << endl;
        cout << "Data: " << m_head->getData() << endl;
        cout << endl;

        m_head = m_head->next_ptr;
        i++;
    }

    m_head = temp;
}
template <typename T>
LList<T>& LList<T>::operator =(LList& copy)
{
    m_head = copy.m_head;

    return *this;
}
template <typename T>
LList<T>& LList<T>::operator =(LList&& move)
{
    m_head = move.m_head;
    move.m_head = 0;

    return *this;
}
```

Some of the errors I am getting:

```
-Error  C2039   'deleteNode': is not a member of 'global namespace' , Error C2039   'getNode': is not a member of '`global namespace'', (more error C2039)...
-Error  C2040   'LList': 'int' differs in levels of indirection from 'Node<T> *'
-Error  C2988   unrecognizable template declaration/definition
```

If you can spot what I'm doing wrong and guide me in the right direction, I would appreciate it very much.

Thank you for helping

Comment: Please show a [mre], where are the errors occurring? Please show the full compiler output rather than the error summaries

Comment: You are putting `<T>` in a lot of places it doesn't belong.